ESP32 With IP Address
I am trying to send data to ThingsBoard in an on-premises environment using ESP32.
However, I need to use the local network, so I cannot use the target server address provided in the ESP32 sample code.
constexpr char THINGSBOARD_SERVER[] = "demo.thingsboard.io";

However, I would like to access it using an IP address instead. For example:
constexpr char THINGSBOARD_SERVER[] = "192.168.0.100";

I would like to use an IP address instead. Do you have a good solution for this?"
Let me know if you need any further tweaks!

if the network is connected to Internet then you can use the name

If ThingsBoard is running on premise, then set the address equal to the IP address of the server that is hosting ThingsBoard.
Here is a link to the head of the Installation options for On premise installs:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/installation-options/
Then you can use the server IP address for variable $THINGSBOARD_HOST_NAME in these connection examples:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/
